# Is it better to use ToCharArray() or ToString() in comparing a string and a char?

Tags: c#

I need to check if a string is equal to a specific char.

At the moment I'm doing it like this:

```
if (InputData.ToCharArray()[0] == 0x18)
```

`InputData` is a string, and any time I get to this point in my code it should always be only one char long.

My question is, would it be preferable to to the comparison in some other way? Like this for example:

```
if (InputData == ((char)0x1c).ToString())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
string InputData = "...";
if (InputData.Length == 1 && InputData[0] == 0x18)
```

Comment: that code gives me this error:
Error 1 'string' does not contain a definition for 'InputData' and no extension method 'InputData' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Works on my side. The error tells me that you are trying to make a call to the method `some_string.InputData`. Such call is absent in my answer.

Comment: To elaborate on why Dmitry's answer works - you don't need to call `ToCharArray`, since System.String has an indexed property called [Chars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars(v=vs.110).aspx) which allows direct access to the Chars comprising the string. `ToCharArray` is used when you want to pass the string to a method which explicitly expects a `char[]`.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do it, for example:

```
string InputData = "...";
if(InputData.Length == 1 && InputData[0].Equals(0x18))
```